# SVG Animation rotate() not working right on Firefox

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, rotatetransform

So I am working on a SVG animation of a simple stopwatch using CSS transform: rotate() and it works perfectly on webkit browsers like chrome, and safari. However on Firefox it behaves quite differently where the second hand which I am trying to animate flies off it's axis. I created a codepen of it here.

```
#stopwatch {
 position: relative;
}
.stopwatch-st0{fill:#E65E39;}
.stopwatch-st1{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#34312D;}
.stopwatch-st2{fill:#34312D;}
#stopwatch:hover #second-hand {
    -webkit-animation: secondAnimate 1s ease;
    animation: secondAnimate1 1s ease;
}
#second-hand {
    --webkit-transform-origin: 12% 78%;
    transform-origin: 12% 78%;
    /*transform: rotate(-55deg);*/
    -webkit-animation: secondAnimate 1s ease;
          animation: secondAnimate 1s ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes secondAnimate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
            transform: rotate(-55deg);
  }

  100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes secondAnimate1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
            transform: rotate(-55deg);
  }
  100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/timherbert/pen/bBXaMW

Comment: Chrome's implementation of transform-origin is buggy. You've coded against that. Firefox's implementation is correct per spec (i.e. the centre of the viewBox).

Comment: Isn't transform-origin supposed to set the origin of that. I know default is 50% 50% so the center of the viewbox but I can't get transform-origin to work in this case at all.

Comment: Just playing with the origin I somehow managed to make it work with the tranform-origin of:
transform-origin: -1836px 2012.5px;